# Prediction retracing warning message while creating LOOCV in CNN keras/tensorflow2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to write a custom for loop in order to execute a LOOCV using tensorflow 2.0 and Keras API. I am testing a CNN regression where each value is represented by 12 molecular images.

My dataset consists of 504 images from 42 molecules and it looks like this:

```
    file                value   intrain
0   mol1_scan0.bmp      6.456   True
1   mol1_scan30.bmp     6.456   True
2   mol1_scan60.bmp     6.456   True
3   mol1_scan90.bmp     6.456   True
4   mol1_scan120.bmp    6.456   True
... ... ... ...
499 mol42_scan210.bmp   6.244   True
500 mol42_scan240.bmp   6.244   True
501 mol42_scan270.bmp   6.244   True
502 mol42_scan300.bmp   6.244   True
503 mol42_scan330.bmp   6.244   True
```

My goal is to create a LOOCV, where at every step of the loop, 12 images are set as validation at a time, this 12 images have to belong to the same molecule. That's controlled by the 'intrain' column.

The loop responsible for creating the LOOCV and running the CNN looks like this:

```
    for lo in range(mols):
    loo = lo+1
    t0= time.time()
    vald = np.repeat(True,mols)
    vald[loo] = False
    vals = []
    for p in range(mols):
        vals.extend(np.repeat(vald[p],views))
    data = pd.DataFrame({'file':paths,'valor':ys,'train':vals})
    train = data[data.train==True]
    validation = data[data.train==False]
    print(f'##### Executing step {loo} out of {mols} ##### {datetime.now()}')
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.)
    train_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=train, directory=original_train,
                                                  color_mode="grayscale",
                                                  x_col='file',
                                                  y_col='valor',
                                                  target_size=(200,220),
                                                  class_mode='raw',
                                                  batch_size=32)
    validation_generator = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=validation, directory=original_train,
                                                  color_mode="grayscale",
                                                  x_col='file',
                                                  y_col='valor',
                                                  target_size=(200,220),
                                                  class_mode='raw',
                                                  batch_size=32,
                                                  shuffle = False)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(200,220,1)))
    model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D((2,2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(220,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer = 'Adam')
    train_steps = train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
    validation_steps = validation_generator.n//validation_generator.batch_size
    history = model.fit(train_generator,steps_per_epoch=train_steps, epochs=1,verbose=0,
                                  validation_data=validation_generator,validation_steps=validation_steps)
    Y_pred = model.predict(validation_generator, validation_generator.n // (validation_generator.batch_size+1))
    Y_pred = Y_pred.flatten()
    Y_true = validation_generator.labels
    Y_lab = np.repeat(loo,12)
    plotagem = pd.DataFrame({'yobs':Y_true,'ypred':Y_pred,'ylab':Y_lab})
    plotagemFinal = pd.concat([plotagemFinal,plotagem])
    t1 = time.time() - t0
    print(f'##### Finalized step {loo} out of {mols} ##### ({datetime.now()} - {round(t1/60,2)} min)\n')
```

When I run this, I get a warning message, indicating that retracing has been triggered...

> WARNING:tensorflow:7 out of the last 7 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function..predict_function at 0x0000023801DD0A60> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.

I found that the problem is caused only by this line:

Y_pred = model.predict(validation_generator, validation_generator.n // (validation_generator.batch_size+1))

I have tried to fix it by following the tips provided by the warning and various other solutions, mainly trying to set the prediction outside the loop, but none of them seem to solve my problem..

Has anyone gone through this kind of issue and could solve it?

I would really appreciate any help or tips regarding not only this warning issue, but the problem as a whole..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

My code was loading the model and the running predict and I had a similar message as warning.

WARNING:tensorflow:11 out of the last 11 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function..predict_function at 0x000001A789F8F288> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.

I placed

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

in front of predict, after loading the model. Magically, the Warning message disappeared. This is a tip from  [Tensorflow 2.0: custom keras metric caused tf.function retracing warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58814130/tensorflow-2-0-custom-keras-metric-caused-tf-function-retracing-warning)

My code looks like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
import time

tstart = time.time()
reconstructed_model = keras.models.load_model("my_model2")

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
image = image.load_img("testimages/1404.jpg", target_size = (28, 28))
# image.show()
input_arr = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image)
input_arr = np.array([input_arr])  # Convert single image to a batch.
result = reconstructed_model.predict(input_arr)

print(result)
print(result[0][0])
print(result[0][1])
# training_set.class_indices
if result[0][1] > 0.9:
    prediction = 'This is a z-pattern'
else:
    prediction = 'This is not a z-pattern'
print(prediction)
print ('display FPS:' , (time.time()-tstart)*1000 , "msec")
```