# Tensorflow 2.0 turn off tf.function retracing for prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to generate prediction intervals for a simple RNN using dropout. I'm using the functional API with `training=True` to enable dropout during testing.

To try different dropout levels, I defined a small function to edit the model configs:

```py
from keras.models import Model, Sequential

def dropout_model(model, dropout):
    conf = model.get_config()
    for layer in conf['layers']:
        if layer["class_name"]=="Dropout":
            layer["config"]["rate"] = dropout
        elif "dropout" in layer["config"].keys():
            layer["config"]["dropout"] = dropout
            layer["config"]["recurrent_dropout"] = 0
            
    model_new = Model.from_config(conf)
    model_new.set_weights(model.get_weights())
    
    return model_new
```

However, when applying different dropout levels multiple times, e.g. using a loop like

```py
for i in range(1, 8):
  dropout = i/10
  model_new = dropout_model(model, dropout)
  print(model_new.predict(input_data))
```

I get this warning message:

> WARNING:tensorflow:9 out of the last 28 calls to <function Model.make_predict_function..predict_function at 0x7f5a8008cd90> triggered tf.function retracing. Tracing is expensive and the excessive number of tracings could be due to (1) creating @tf.function repeatedly in a loop, (2) passing tensors with different shapes, (3) passing Python objects instead of tensors. For (1), please define your @tf.function outside of the loop. For (2), @tf.function has experimental_relax_shapes=True option that relaxes argument shapes that can avoid unnecessary retracing. For (3), please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/performance#python_or_tensor_args and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function for  more details.

I already tried using `@tf.function`, `@tf.function(experimental_relax_shapes=True)` and `tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()` suggested for [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62298471/9220442) without success.